# DJANGO COMMENTS_APP, how can i use it? Didn't work post comment

Tags: django, comments

I try customize django comments module (delete field url)
i create empty class VSComments and form

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.comments.forms import CommentForm
from vs_comments.models import VSComment

class VSCommentForm(CommentForm):
    """
    No url Form
   """
VSCommentForm.base_fields.pop('url')
```

#### `__init__`

```
from vs_comments.models import VSComment
from vs_comments.forms import VSCommentForm

def get_model():
    return VSComment

def get_form():
    return VSCommentForm
```

also url(r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),

include 'vs_comments' and 'django.contrib.comments' into INSTALLED_APPS and COMMENTS_APP = 'vs_comments'

As result, I have right form, without url field, but posting comments doesn't work

---

soution add to the form class

```
def get_comment_create_data(self):
# Use the data of the superclass, and remove extra fields
    return dict(
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.target_object),
        object_pk    = force_unicode(self.target_object._get_pk_val()),
        comment      = self.cleaned_data["comment"],
        name         = self.cleaned_data["name"],
        submit_date  = datetime.datetime.now(),
        site_id      = settings.SITE_ID,
        is_public    = True,
        is_removed   = False,
    )
```

For admin panel

```
class VSCommentAdmin(CommentsAdmin):
    """
    all like native comments
    """
admin.site.register(Comment, CommentsAdmin)
```

But now didn't work tags render_comment_list and other. No any errors, only empty result
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any error trace ?

I think it doesn't work because the validation of your VSCommentForm uses the validator of CommentForm, and the "url" field is missing in your customized form.

You should read more on customized form that inherits from another form and its validation :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#processing-the-data-from-a-form

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CustomFormFields

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/